# Convert Maybe String to (Maybe?) Integer

Tags: haskell

I would like to convert a Maybe String type to an Integer.

My actual code is:

```
  let rule = getParamRule args -- this is a Maybe String type
  let rule_int = read rule::Int -- I would like to convert to (Maybe) Integer
  print rule
  print rule_int
```

```
test.hs:26:23: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Maybe String’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: String
        Actual type: Maybe String
    • In the first argument of ‘read’, namely ‘rule’
      In the expression: read rule :: Maybe Int
      In an equation for ‘rule_int’: rule_int = read rule :: Maybe Int
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Text.Read.readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe)

> `readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`
>
> Parse a string using the Read instance. Succeeds if there is exactly
>   one valid result.
>
> ```
> > readMaybe "123" :: Maybe Int
> Just 123
>
> > readMaybe "hello" :: Maybe Int
> Nothing
> ```

Before using that, you need to import the module using

```
import Text.Read
```

at the beginning of your file (after the `module ...` line, if you have one).

Note that you can search [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) *by type*. In this case, searching for `String -> Maybe Int` shows `readMaybe` as the 11th result. Could be better, but it is still shown in the first page.

Comment: Thanks. I've got this error: `Variable not in scope: readMaybe :: Maybe String -> Maybe Int` with the code: `readMaybe rule::Maybe Int`

Comment: This is not working, got this error now: `Couldn't match type ‘Maybe’ with ‘IO’`

Comment: @AlexisR That looks like another issue: post the full code editing your answer.

Comment: You can find the full code at: https://pastebin.com/XEv9FbFg because I would like that this code had an expiration date.

Comment: @AlexisR In your case, you need `let rule_int :: Maybe Int ; rule_int = rule >>= readMaybe`. The issue here is that `rule` is not a `String`, but only a `Maybe String`. So you need to handle more cases: 1) `rule` can be `Nothing`, 2) `rule` can be `Just str`, but `readMaybe str` fails with `Nothing`, 3) like 2, but `readMaybe str` succeeds with `Just i`. The operator `>>=` handles the cases returning `Nothing` for 1 and 2, and `Just i` for 3.

Comment: @AlexisR If you don't want to use `>>=`, you can use a more primitive `case rule of Nothing -> Nothing ; Just str -> readMaybe str` to safely "extract" the `str` from `rule`, if there is one. Still, `>>=` is commonly used for this.